# How to design function for Random Decrement technique in python and implement the function?

Tags: matlab, signal-analysis, python, continuous-signals, scipy

I was looking into a technique called Random decrement technique from the following links/articles:

- [How can I use Random Decrement Method to convert a non-stationary
  signal into a decay function using Matlab?](https://www.researchgate.net/post/How-can-I-use-Random-Decrement-Method-to-convert-a-non-stationary-signal-into-a-decay-function-using-Matlab)
- [Random Decrement Technique](https://github.com/zwynne/random-decrement-waves)
- [Using the Random Decrement Method for the Decentralized Acquisition
  of Modal Data](https://kuscholarworks.ku.edu/bitstream/handle/1808/7752/Dande_ku_0099M_11262_DATA_1.pdf;sequence=1)

I found out that this technique was created in MATLAB which can be found in the following link ([Damping ratio estimation from ambient vibrations (SDOF)](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/55557-damping-ratio-estimation-from-ambient-vibrations-sdof)). I tried to convert the code into python using smop, however, I think I made a mistake with the conversion. I feel that I misused smop package and tried recoding the converted file, but, I feel that I might have done something wrong. The code and conversion can be found below:

***MATLAB:***

```
function [R,t] = RDT(y,ys,T,dt)
%
% [R] = RDT(y,ys,T,dt) returns the free-decay response (R) by
% using the random decrement technique (RDT) to the time serie y, with a
% triggering value ys, and for a duration T
%
% INPUT:
%   y: time series of ambient vibrations: vector of size [1xN]
%   dt : Time step
%   ys: triggering values (ys < max(abs(y)) and here ys~=0)
%   T: Duration of subsegments (T<dt*(numel(y)-1))
% OUTPUT:
%   R: impusle response function
%   t: time vector asociated to R
% 
% Author: E. Cheynet - UiB - last modified 14-05-2020
%%
if T>=dt*(numel(y)-1)
    error('Error: subsegment length is too large');
else
    % number of time step per block
    nT = round(T/dt); % sec
end
if ys==0
    error('Error: ys must be different from zero')
elseif or(ys >=max(y),ys <=min(y)),
    error('Error:  ys must verifiy : min(y) < ys < max(y)')
else
    % find triggering value
    ind=find(diff(y(1:end-nT)>ys)~=0)+1;
    
end
% construction of decay vibration
R = zeros(numel(ind),nT);
for ii=1:numel(ind)
    R(ii,:)=y(ind(ii):ind(ii)+nT-1);
end
% averaging to remove the random part
R = mean(R);
% normalize the R
R = R./R(1);
% time vector corresponding to the R
t = linspace(0,T,numel(R));
end

coeff = 5; % interpolation coefficient
newDT = median(diff(interp(t,coeff)));
newY = interp(y,coeff);
% triggering value
ys = max(abs(y))/5;
% subsegment duration
Ts = round(t(end)/30);

% RDT function
[IRF,newT] = RDT(newY,ys,Ts,newDT);
% get the envelop of the curve with the hilbert transform:
envelop = abs(hilbert(IRF));
envelop(1)=IRF(1);
clf;close all;
figure
hold on; box on;
plot(newT,IRF,'b',newT,envelop,'k');
xlabel('time (s)')
ylabel('normalized displacement')
xlim([0,Ts])
set(gcf,'color','w')
% fit an exponential decay to the envelop
optionPlot = 1;
wn = 2*pi*0.2; % -> obtained with peak picking method (fast way)
[zeta] = expoFit(envelop,newT,wn,optionPlot);
legend('IRF','envelop',' best fit')
```

***Python:***

```
# Generated with SMOP  0.41
# from libsmop import *
# RDT.m

from scipy.signal import chirp, spectrogram
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

    
# @function
def RDT(y=None,ys=None,T=None,dt=None,*args,**kwargs):
    # varargin = RDT.varargin
    # nargin = RDT.nargin

    
    # [R] = RDT(y,ys,T,dt) returns the free-decay response (R) by
# using the random decrement technique (RDT) to the time series y, with a
# triggering value ys, and for a duration T
    
    # INPUT:
#   y: time series of ambient vibrations: vector of size [1xN]
#   dt : Time step
#   ys: triggering values (ys < max(abs(y)) and here ys~=0)
#   T: Duration of subsegments (T<dt*(np.size(y)-1))
# OUTPUT:
#   R: impusle response function
#   t: time vector asociated to R
# 
# Author: E. Cheynet - UiB - last modified 14-05-2020
    
    if T >= np.dot(dt,(np.size(y) - 1)):
        error('Error: subsegment length is too large')
    else:
        # number of time step per block
        nT=round(T / dt)
# RDT.m:22
    
    if ys == 0:
        error('Error: ys must be different from zero')
    else:
        if ys >= max(y) or ys <= min(y):
            error('Error:  ys must verifiy : min(y) < ys < max(y)')
        else:
            # find triggering value
            ind=np.nonzero(np.diff(y(np.arange(1,y[-1] - nT)) > ys) != 0) + 1
# RDT.m:30
    
    # construction of decay vibration
    R=zeros(np.size(ind),nT)
# RDT.m:34
    for ii in np.arange(1,np.size(ind)).reshape(-1):
        R[ii,np.arange()]=y(np.arange(ind(ii),ind(ii) + nT - 1))
# RDT.m:36
    
    # averaging to remove the random part
    R=mean(R)
# RDT.m:39
    # normalize the R
    R=R / R(1)
# RDT.m:41
    # time vector corresponding to the R
    t=np.linspace(0,T,np.size(R))
# RDT.m:43
    return R,t
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = np.linspace(0, 10, 3000)
    w = chirp(t, f0=6, f1=1, t1=10, method='linear')
    plt.plot(t, w)
    plt.title("Linear Chirp, f(0)=6, f(10)=1")
    plt.xlabel('t (sec)')
    plt.show()
    
    N = 3000 # number of time step
    # t = linspace(0,1800,N); # time
    dt = np.median(np.diff(t)) # time step
    fs = 1/dt
    
    coeff = 5 # interpolation coefficient
    newDT = np.median(np.diff(np.interp(coeff, t, w)))
    # newDT = np.median(np.diff(interp1d(t, t, w)))
    newY = np.interp(coeff, t, w)
    # triggering value
    ys = max(abs(w))/5
    # subsegment duration
    Ts = round(t[-1]/30)
    
    R, t = RDT(newY,ys,Ts,newDT)
    
    pass
```

I want to obtain a function for RDT and fit the decreasing decrement using an envelope to make sure that it follows decreasing /impulse signal. What could be my mistake here and obtain a reasonable impulse signal? An equation for RD can be found in the following article and photo. ([Design of a Random Decrement Method Based Structural Health Monitoring System](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/274948642_Design_of_a_Random_Decrement_Method_Based_Structural_Health_Monitoring_System))

[image]

I want to implement the function onto for instance signals similar to the ones in the photo below.

[image]

The errors I am getting:

```
ind=np.nonzero(np.diff(y(np.arange(1,y[-1] - nT)) > ys) != 0) + 1
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable


newDT = np.median(np.diff(np.interp(coeff, t, w)))
raise ValueError("diff requires input that is at least one dimensional")
ValueError: diff requires input that is at least one dimensional
```

Also, I’m mainly stuck at this line:

Python:

```
            # find triggering value
            ind=np.nonzero(np.diff(y(np.arange(1,y[-1] - nT)) > ys) != 0) + 1
```

MATLAB:

```
    % find triggering value
    ind=find(diff(y(1:end-nT)>ys)~=0)+1;
```

So, how would I convert this line for the find in MATLAB to python code?

Comment: This probably isn't the right place for debugging code, but if you can narrow it down to a specific signal processing question we may be able to generate more responses. Right now this reads as here is my python version of MATLAB code and it doesn't match, why?

Comment: @DanBoschen I edited the question.

Comment: It's still a python language question which doesn't really belong here, so better in stackoverflow with your last point "The errors I am getting" would likely be sufficient to get an answer to your question. For this you are using () when you should be using [] to select items in y. In python () will always call a function and y is not a function. And for the second error check what np.interp is returning to ensure it is a 1D array (and ensure t and w are 1D arrays). Good luck!